# How to make a clickable object of an entire Excel Workbook (.xslx) in Word with vb?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Exactly the question above.

Here's an example of what I'm doing for the .txt files:

```
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(Count).Cells(3).Range.InlineShapes.AddOlEObject _
        ClassType:="Word.Document", FileName:=filePath & "ZXLPF3G8H6W.Audit20220815120733.txt"
```

This makes the .txt clickable and opens the file.

But when I do it with a .xlsx it doesn't work:

```
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(Count).Cells(3).Range.InlineShapes.AddOlEObject _
        ClassType:="Excel.Workbook", FileName:=filePath & "*.xlsx"
```

Note: There's only 1 .xlsx in the directory. I'm using (*) because it will be renamed.

Any help would be appreciated - thank you.

Comment: When the .xlsx is opened I want it to open separately outside of the Word document. Not inside the Word document as an excel chart.

Comment: I'm not sure on the class type being correct, maybe `excel.sheet.12`.  What is the issue you are getting?  Is the workbook displayed as an icon?  How is it set up, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: After trying ClassType:="excel.sheet.12" , the error code gives me: "Word cannot obtain the data from path (the file). If I do this with a sheet it will work. If I do this with a .txt it will work. It won't work with a workbook and I'm trying to figure that out.

Comment: FWIW I tried the same code as you with a .xlsx and it worked fine here. In the { EMBED } field that Word created, the "correct" CLSID/PROGID was generated, i.e. even when I actually left "Word.Document" in my code by mistake when I tried to embed a .xlsx, WOrd still used "Excel.Workbook.12" or whatever in the { EMBED } field. My  tactic would be to start with a very simple new xlsx and make sure it's in a folder trusted by Office (just in case that's a thing).

Comment: As for how you want the object to be opened when you click, I'm not sure that you can really exercise any control over that any more if you are relying on Word's built-n response to a click. OLE had promise, a couple of decades ago or so, but it then MS went in a different set of directions.